# Store User Token, If Invalid token - present Login page,

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

Learning iOS Swift programming and like to know how to implement **user login process** ?

The backend-iOS mechanism is this :

- User login with email and Password,
- The Server returns user token and user id
- In subsequent requests, user token and user id is sent to fetch data/work with the App.

I have doubt in iOS implementation.

1. Will be storing User token and User id in Core Data. Will there be
   any slowness  if I get the user token on every screen from Core
   Data?
2. If the login token expires or is invalid on any screen, how to fall back to login page? Should I check the JSON output and have code "present login VC" on every screen? Any streamlined way to have abstract the code to a swift or cocoa touch file?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are many approaches. It's all depends on you, how you will manage it. I can point you two examples, how I manage it by myself.

### Using `NSOperation`.

There was an awesome session on WWDC 2015, about advanced `NSOperations`. [Here it is.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/)

Basically, you create a subclass of `NSOperaton` and make other operations depend on it. In your case, you will have operation of user login, and all other operations will depend on user login (of course only ones, who needs it). If it succeed, then operation will execute. In user login operation, you will check, if user already logged in, and you have a token, if not, present logging screen.

There is also awesome library called `Operations`, based on that WWDC talk. [Here it is.](https://github.com/danthorpe/Operations)

### Using `PromiseKit`.

Here is another one, using `PromiseKit`. It is not really much difference from operations, but, in my opinion, a little simpler. You create `Promise` that ensures that you did login. It is very simple to make a chain of promises, so you promise a user login and chain anything else from it. If login succeed, chain of promises continues executing.

It's all based on another awesome library, `PromiseKit`. [Here it is](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)

It is very powerful and very simple to use, once you understand the thing. It is very well documented, and has a bunch of tutorials [here](http://promisekit.org).

There are many other approaches, so you can choose any of it, and combine one with other however you like.

Asking on your first question, you make it asynchronous, so it is not so much matter about slowness of `CoreData` as you make a web request.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Looks great!

Answer (score 0):

1 - well, yes, a bit. But I doubt you will notice any lag or anything: CoreData is really fast and it won't take any significant amount of time to fetch just one object. Alternatively, your CoreData object that holds this data (let's call it `User`) can be a property of your subclass of `UIApplicationDelegate` (let's call it `MyAppDelegate`). You will fetch this `User` in
`- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and update it on login/logout/expire/etc. In such way you can access it from everywhere, and you don't need to fetch it from CoreData anytime you need it.
Also, instead of CoreData you can use iOS Keychain. (Here is [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) that might help with this).

2 - again, you can use `MyAppDelegate`. For example you can add method to it, that will save current navigation state, and change root controller of `UIWindow` to your `LoginViewController`. Or it will present `LoginViewController` on top of current controller. After successful login you will return navigation stack to previous state.
Also you can move this code to some kind of `NavigationController` - class that will handle this situation. It will have something like
`func checkToken(Dictionary response, UIViewController currentController) -> Bool`. If token is valid, it just returns `true`, and if not, it returns `false` and handles navigation to `LoginViewController`, and after login - back to `currentController`. This `NavigationController` can be property of `MyAppDelegate`, it can be singleton, created every time you need it, or you can pass it along to every `UIViewController` that you show.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I preferred Core Data because I'm trying to save many user details in the app. 
Regarding 2, I guess this scenario is faced by every App developer, why there is NO much tutorial on the web. I mean, a user token will expires and user's will definitely face this issue, right?